# tkinter python and global command

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, procedural-programming

I'm new to python, and i started to use tkinter to build a simple GUI.
I was looking around in some examples and i saw that there is a few ways to program with tkinter (or generally program)

The first way is procedural and the recommended way is OOP(correct me if i'm wrong) so here is the question:

assume i got this code and i've imported the library:

```
root = Tk()
ipLabel = Label(root, text='IP Address:', fg='blue', bg='cyan')
ip = Entry(root)
ipLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
ip.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=1, pady=3)
root.mainloop()
```

now since all the code in the global scope i can just access the entry by doing `ip.get()` from any other function or class

Now let's take the same code in the second way:

```
class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.Widgets()

    def Widgets(self):
        ipLabel = Label(self, text='IP Address:', fg='blue', bg='cyan')
        ip = Entry(self)
        ipLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
        ip.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=1, pady=3)

MyApp = App()
MyApp.mainloop()
```

what is the best way to access the ip entry from another class or function? what i tried to do and it's working is just to put global for this variables inside the function

```
def Widgets(self):
        global ip
        ipLabel = Label(top_frame, text='IP Address:', fg='blue', bg='cyan')
        ip = Entry(top_frame)
```

I want to know if there is another way to do it and what is the best way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace ip with self.ip in App.Widgets(), and then you can access it from elsewhere, e.g. MyApp.ip.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it seems to work, this is a better way to use than global?

Comment: This is the correct way to do it if you're using OOP.